# Is there a way to make text unselectable on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, textselection

I'm building an HTML UI with some text elements, such as tab names, which look bad when selected. Unfortunately, it's very easy for a user to double-click a tab name, which selects it by default in many browsers.

I might be able to solve this with a JavaScript trick (I'd like to see those answers, too) -- but I'm really hoping there's something in CSS/HTML directly that works across all browsers.

Comment: While many of the examples listed here work, keep in mind nothing prevents someone from just looking at the source code and copying the text.

Comment: Depending on your needs http://stackoverflow.com/q/4117466/298479 might also be a valid solution for you.

Answer (score 208, accepted):

In most browsers, this can be achieved using CSS:

```css
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

For IE < 10 and Opera, you will need to use the `unselectable` attribute of the element you wish to be unselectable. You can set this using an attribute in HTML:

```
<div id="foo" unselectable="on" class="unselectable">...</div>
```

Sadly this property isn't inherited, meaning you have to put an attribute in the start tag of every element inside the `<div>`. If this is a problem, you could instead use JavaScript to do this recursively for an element's descendants:

```
function makeUnselectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        makeUnselectable(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

makeUnselectable(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

Comment: you can use this selector [unselectable=on]{...} then you avoid putting extra class

Comment: According to http://dev.l-c-n.com/CSS3-selectors/browser-support.php , this selector should be supported in IE8 and above, and possibly IE7.

Comment: @JoeCoder: Yes, I believe attribute selectors do work in IE 7, although not IE 6.

Comment: Just curious, is there an advantage to using *.unselectable over .unselectable in the stylesheet?

Comment: @BrianMortenson: None at all: they are equivalent. I have a very old habit of including the `*` in that kind of selector to remind myself explicitly that I'm matching all tag names. However, I no longer find it helpful and it's now just pure habit, so I've pretty much stopped doing it now.

Comment: funny that @TimDown harvested another 113 rep by copying his answer from this question's duplicate. oh wait! <click> 114 ;)

Comment: @ericsoco: Yeah. It's an interesting issue: if others have posted answers that people are upvoting and I think I have a better answer, should I post it? The system still allows people to find, view and vote on answers to closed questions, after all. I can't deny that desire for rep has occasionally motivated me to add an answer to a duplicate question on a pet subject rather than vote to close it.

Comment: of course you should and of course you should post your answers everywhere they can be found.  the point of answering, ultimately, is not about rep -- it's about providing answers in places they can be found.  i'm all for it. </OT>

Comment: @venimus I would favor classes over xpath selectors like [unselectable=on] in CSS. In jquery they're good if you narrow down to an immediate container first but in CSS, selectors are parsed right to left so it's still a blanket check of every element and every element's unselectable attribute using the performance-meh xpath engine. Likewise, I believe, with the querySelector API which I'm guessing typically hooks into the CSS/xpath selector engines directly. This may change over time as browsers find perf tweaks but I would definitely keep this in mind when supporting IE<=8, maybe <=9.

Comment: Probably you are right, but I think early optimizations are evil.
Also you won't need the JS if you use [unselectable=on] * {...}

Comment: @venimus: You can't avoid the JS if you want IE <= 9 support and don't want to put `unselectable="on"` on every element. All you can avoid with your selector is adding `class="unselectable"`.

Answer (score 41):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Disable Text Selection script- © Dynamic Drive DHTML code library (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit Dynamic Drive at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for full source code

***********************************************/


function disableSelection(target){

    if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined") //IE route
        target.onselectstart=function(){return false}

    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined") //Firefox route
        target.style.MozUserSelect="none"

    else //All other route (ie: Opera)
        target.onmousedown=function(){return false}

    target.style.cursor = "default"
}



//Sample usages
//disableSelection(document.body) //Disable text selection on entire body
//disableSelection(document.getElementById("mydiv")) //Disable text selection on element with id="mydiv"


</script>
```

**EDIT**

Code apparently comes from http://www.dynamicdrive.com

Comment: Is there any update for the Opera or making elements unselectable still not supported?

Comment: Why are you changing the cusor style to 'default' in the last case? Otherwise +1

Comment: Infact, you are changing it in all cases (indent is misleading)

Answer (score 36):

All of the correct CSS variations are:

```css
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: According to this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25015048/642706), the order of those two webkit settings may be critical, where the `-webkit-user-select:` should come before the `-webkit-touch-callout:`. I have not verified this.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
<div onselectstart="return false">some stuff</div>
```

Simple, but effective... works in current versions of all major browsers.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in firefox.

Comment: This is IE only attribute. which makes it redundant.

Comment: Worked perfectly for our app (we only target IE users).

Comment: This was the only way I could get the effect needed for text selection happening in IE11 when doing a shift-click select in an ag-Grid.

Answer (score 11):

For Firefox you can apply the CSS declaration "-moz-user-select" to "none".
Check out their documentation, *[user-select](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-user-select)*.

It's a "preview" of the future "user-select" as they say, so maybe [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) or [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)-based browsers will support that. I also recall finding something for Internet Explorer, but I don't remember what :).

Anyway, unless it's a specific situation where text-selecting makes some dynamic functionality fail, you shouldn't really override what users are expecting from a webpage, and that is being able to select any text they want.

Comment: Likewise in Safari/Chrome/etc. -khtml-user-select:none;

Comment: Is this likely to appear in the CSS standards though?

Answer (score 9):

I'm finding some level of success with the CSS described here http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html:

```css
::selection {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

It took care of most of the issues I was having with some ThemeRoller `ul` elements in an AIR application (WebKit engine). Still getting a small (approx. 15 x 15) patch of nothingness that gets selected, but half the page was being selected before.

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely position divs over the text area with a z-index higher and give these divs a transparent [GIF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format) background graphic.

Note after a bit more thought - You'd need to have these 'covers' be linked so clicking on them would take you to where the tab was supposed to, which means you could/should do this with the anchor element set to `display:box`, width and height set as well as the transparent background image.

Comment: This is what flickr does

Comment: This kind of hack is terrible.  I'd avoid it personally.

Comment: The tiny little problem with this method are the links, as you mentioned, and any other interactions you'd want to have with the main window...

Answer (score 4):

For an example of why it might be desirable to suppress selection, see [SIMILE TImeline](http://simile.mit.edu/timeline/), which uses drag-and-drop to explore  the timeline, during which accidental vertical mouse movement causes the labels to be highlighted unexpectedly, which looks weird.

Answer (score 4):

For Safari, `-khtml-user-select: none`, just like Mozilla's `-moz-user-select` (or, in JavaScript, `target.style.KhtmlUserSelect="none";`).

Answer (score 3):

> "If your content is really interesting, then there is little you can
>   ultimately do to protect it"

That's true, but most copying, in my experience, has nothing to do with "ultimately" or geeks or determined plagiarists or anything like that. It's usually casual copying by clueless people, and even a simple, easily defeated protection (easily defeated by folks like us, that is) works quite well to stop them. They don't know anything about "view source" or caches or anything else... heck, they don't even know what a web browser is or that they're using one.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a [Sass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) mixin (scss) for those interested. [Compass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_Project)/CSS 3 doesn't seem to have a user-select mixin.

```
// @usage use within a rule
// ex. img {@include user-select(none);}
// @param assumed valid user-select value
@mixin user-select($value)
{
    & {
        -webkit-touch-callout: $value;
        -webkit-user-select: $value;
        -khtml-user-select: $value;
        -moz-user-select: $value;
        -ms-user-select: $value;
        user-select: $value;
    }
}
```

Though Compass would do it in a more robust way, i.e. only add support for vendors you've chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Images can be selected too.

There are limits to using JavaScript to deselect text, as it might happen even in places where you want to select. To ensure a rich and successful career, steer clear of all requirements that need ability to influence or manage the browser beyond the ordinary... unless, of course, they are paying you extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

If it looks bad you can use CSS to change the appearance of selected sections.

Answer (score 1):

Any JavaScript or CSS method is easily circumvented with Firebug (like Flickr's case).

You can use the [`::selection` pseudo-element](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/selection.html) in CSS to alter the highlight color.

If the tabs are links and the [dotted rectangle in active state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links) is of concern, you can remove that too (consider usability of course).

Answer (score 1):

There are many occasions when turning off selectability enhances the user experience.

For instance allowing the user to copy a block of text on the page without copying the text of any interface elements associated with it (that would become interspersed within the text being copied).

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Firefox interestingly enough if I remove the write line it doesn't work.
Anyone have any insight why the write line is needed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(".");
document.body.style.MozUserSelect='none';
</script>
```

Comment: I guess body might not be accessible in DOM before it has content, thus you can't set it's style before you write something in the document.