# When I click on a link, most browsers draw a dotted box around it. How can I prevent this?

Tags: html, css

When I click on a link, most browsers draw a dotted box around it. It's easiest to see if the link is opened in a new window, since the original page sticks around.

Can this be stopped?

Comment: I think you should ask yourself why you're trying to prevent this... it's purely a browser display feature that should be up to the end user to enable to disable.

Comment: I think *you* should ask *yourself* why you're trying to prevent me from trying to prevent this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put this in your CSS

```
-moz-outline: none;
outline: none;
```

Here's a [more detailed breakdown](http://sonspring.com/journal/removing-dotted-links) and a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Answer (score 5):

http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

better use:

```
a:active {   
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
a { 
    outline: none;
}
```

it's more specific. otherwise you might suppress too many things at once. and if you care for accessibility make sure to give the users who can't use a mouse some other way of knowing which link is active or focused.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the javascript `blur` function on the link after it's been clicked.  The `blur` function removes focus off the link so it won't be drawn with that dotted box around it.

If you're using jQuery, then you could implement such a solution like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $(this).blur();
    });
});
```