# Change color of dotted border on button

Tags: html, button, colors, border

I have a problem with a button in one of my forms, when a user clicks the button, it shows this black dotted border inside it. I would like to remove this, but I don't know how. I haven't set this border in the CSS...

[image: Button]

((For those wondering; the caption means "search"))

---

I searched some time ago, but with "dashed" instead of "dotted" and therefore found nothing. I searched with "dotted" now and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links), sorry, but is there any way to change the color of this border? (I think this only applies to firefox?)

Comment: Are you aware that this way you can't find the button anymore by keyboard navigation?

Comment: @BalusC, no I wasn't, I assumed the :active-event would kick in and save my day, but it obviously didn't. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Solved it by using button:focus

Comment: Unfortunately, those pseudoselectors doesn't work flawlessly in IE.

Comment: Works in IE 8, and the audience of my page uses either that or Firefox. (School PCs)

Comment: Ah, school, you're lucky. Keep this in mind for the real work though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry for not being clear about the question: This happened when it was clicked, and I had tried the outline-attribute, but the pesky Firefox wouldn't accept it. By reading a little in the other thread, I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links/199319#199319):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

That is the [`outline`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_outline.asp)

You can change it like this:

```
button {
    outline: 3px dashed #f0f;
    /* or, just the colour */
    outline-color: #f0f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is controlled by the [`outline` CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#dynamic-outlines).  To remove it, add the following rules (or similar) to your stylesheet:

```
button.search {
    outline: none;
    -moz-outline: none; /* Firefox 1.0 and earlier, if you care */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments:

> Are you aware that this way you can't find the button anymore by keyboard navigation?
>
> no I wasn't, I assumed the :active-event would kick in and save my day, but it obviously didn't. Do you know any solution?

consider

```
onclick="this.blur();"
```

Comment: i wouldn't recommend this, since this way it's actually *impossible* to use the keyboard to select it. but turning off the outline, it's just invisible that the button is selected.

Comment: nickf, you're confusing onclick with onfocus.