# CSS Firefox - How to deactivate the dotted border ( firefox click indicator )?

Tags: css, firefox, browser, webbrowser-control

This click indicator is a disgusting piece for my recent web projects.. I hate this! - How can I say to my Firefox browser that he should not mark the clicked object?

[image]

Comment: Removing the outline entirely without providing some sort of :focus or :active visual indication throws a road block in your accessibility. Those users who use keyboards to navigate your site rely on those outlines to indicate which element they've tabbed to. You can style them, but I wouldn't remove them entirely.

Comment: Comment above by clrux is dead on.  It's sometimes preferable to add a focus indicator to a child element for better color contrast and visual accessibility.  Hopefully that's the kind of stuff people are trying implement here.  Just removing the focus indicator it is a big no no.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Provided that your menu items are not input elements (say, buttons), you can hide it using CSS, like so:

```
element { outline: none; }
```

Answer (score 14):

a {
outline: none;
}

Comment: In my case I had to add !important to there to get it to stick.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing helped (Firefox 20.1) until this:

```
a:focus, a:active,
button,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
select::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It's a moving target folks.  You'll need to add
`border: none !important;`
as well for this to work now.  Annoying.

Answer (score 2):

this is more accurate:

```
a { outline: none!important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific to @ioannis-karadimas, you could remove the outline on hover (assuming mouse input) but leave it for focus (assuming keyboard input). This would retain most of the accessibility. That being said:

```
element:hover { outline: none; }
element:focus { // leave the focus }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links), adding `outline:0` will also do the trick.

```
.selector{ outline:0; }
```

If you don't want to have the border shown to any element in your website, try the following,

```
:focus { outline:none; }
::-moz-focus-inner { border:0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might hate it, but your customers might not. Generally speaking overriding browser functionality is a great way to confuse users and inspire them not to visit your site.

Comment: Yeah I agree. A consistent user experience is the a and o for a good website.. but some websites need to break those usabillity rules.

Comment: Well in the given context I can see no obvious justification (from the screenie).

Answer (score 0):

Crazy solution:

```
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner{
    border: 1px dotted transparent;
}
```

but I dislike it.

Indeed Firefox 12.0 is marking a dotted on input type="button" when I click it. `outline:none` does nothing for `:active, :focus, ...`