# How to remove the "Dotted Border" on clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see

[image]

I want to somehow remove the dotted lines after the button has been clicked.Any ideas how ?

Thanks

GUYS : This is the current status of my CSS ansd HTML but still no USE:

```
.myButton input {
position:absolute;
display:block;
top: 5%;
left:87%;
height: 44px;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
width: 43px;
font: bold 13px sans-serif;;
color:#333;
background: url("hover.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
text-decoration: none;
}
.myButton input:hover {  
background-position: 0 -44px;
color: #049;
outline: 0;
}
.myButton input:active {
background-position: 0 -88px;
color:#fff;
outline: 0;
}

input:active, input:focus {
      outline: 0;
}

<div class="myButton">
<input type="submit" value="">
</div>
```

Nothing seems to be happening !!

Comment: You should keep them for accessibility.

Comment: Guys,I have edited the post..Still no use !!

Comment: cay you check my updated answer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Firefox - How to deactivate the dotted border ( firefox click indicator )?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285970/css-firefox-how-to-deactivate-the-dotted-border-firefox-click-indicator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible with pure HTML as well:

```
<a href="..." hidefocus="hidefocus">...</a>
```

And with JavaScript you can do that on all links:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(evt) {
   //hide focus:
   var arrLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
   for (var i = 0; i < arrLinks.length; i++) {
       arrLinks[i].hideFocus = "true";
}
```

Comment: i was only having this issue in ie7 and older. but adding the hidefocus worked for me

Comment: Cheers @nate glad this was useful for you. :)

Answer (score 17):

You have to style the `<a>` like:

```
a {outline: none}
```

Comment: it actually needs the `!important` rule to work: `a {outline: none !important}`

Answer (score 6):

use the below code

```
a:active
    {
    outline: none;
    }
```

try for other browsers also

```
a:focus
{
-moz-outline-style: none;
}
a:focus { outline:none }
```

Comment: I suggest to use a CSS class for this, so all other links still keep the "you were here" behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Despite my comment on your question,

> You should keep them for
>   accessibility.

You can find [your CSS-trick here for this](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)

(Anyway, you should keep them.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    #myElement { outline: 0; }
```

Try this on your element, i dont now if is an image, div, button, link. But it works

Comment: This is a very helpful answer. I have a div that I wanted to remove the outline from and this works. Inline, my code looks like this `<div>  <img src="img/heatbar.png" alt="Bar"><a style="display:block;width:16.6%;height:80px;position:absolute;top:0px; outline: 0;" class="tilelink" href="#"></a></div>` This is part of some code which display 6 "tile regions" across the page. Each region is clickable and the outline does not appear when the region is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the outline on active and on focus, but hide it on clicking a link, you can add in css:

A.No-Outline    {outline-style:none;}

and use script:

```
$('A').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('No-Outline');
},function() {
    $(this).removeClass('No-Outline');
});
```

you must be hover befor clicking, so it does the job.