# Is there anyway to remove the border around clicked links in IE8 & below?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove the “Dotted Border” on clicking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374622/how-to-remove-the-dotted-border-on-clicking)

I know this question has been asked multiple times but despite the supposed solutions I still see the ugly borders, which go around any padding I add to links which looks stupid. Basically I'm asking if there even IS a way around that in older versions of IE, specifically 8 and below.

I understand that it will cause some accessibility issues, but it's not going to affect the majority of users coming on my site.

Any help would be appreciated ... I would post my CSS but my files are on my home PC and I'm at work, Sorry.

Comment: The solutions you see may work but you might have not cleared your internet cache?  Ctrl f5 and see if it fixes it for you.

Comment: Hmm, that's true I noticed CTRL + SHIFT + R didn't work in IE so I  gave up on that. I'll try it when I get home. Thanks

Comment: Does a:active, a:visited {outline: none;} not work?

Comment: @Adrift in most cases it is a caching issue, we've all been there once in our lives.  Open your browser clear the cache and you should be good.

Comment: a:active, a:visited {outline: none;} will not work in IE8 or lower because it is not supported, no.

Comment: Nope it doesn't .. just tried it out locally on my work PC

Comment: I already mentioned that, I'm aware, but I'm not expecting many users that will need the accessibility.

Comment: This has indeed been asked multiple times; search for e.g. “remove dotted” to find other existing questions.

Comment: I couldn't think of a fitting string to find it, but even so, the few that I did find didn't work. I apologize though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```css
a:focus, a:active {
    outline:none;
    ie-dummy:expression(this.hideFocus = true);
    border: 0px none;
}
```

Comment: edit: I'm an idiot and didn't clear my cache! sorry! Best solution thus far, thanks.

Comment: There is your upvote! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your question:

http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Removing-Dotted-Border-on-Clicked-Links

Comment: So there is no javascript-less solution? I'm okay with that, I just thought it would involve less .. thanks though

Comment: Unfortunately not that has been properly vetted out.  As a side note, removing the dotted border around a link is sometimes a bad idea if you care about tabbed browsing and/or accessibility, but I'm not sure either of those things will bother you :)

Comment: I'm not expecting many users that come to my site will need the accessibility .. so no it doesn't bother me. Thanks for the link though, you gave me the only working solution thus far. If I can't find a lighter one I'll accept this answer.