# Unwanted outline or border around button when clicked

Tags: html, css, button, border, outline

I have a styled button on my website. But when I click it, it creates an unwanted border or outline (I don't know which). How can I remove that border? Below is all the code that pertains to the button.

```css
button {
    border: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>this is my button</button>
```

Comment: Which browser? What platform? Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I cant notice any border after clicking it.. Can you explain on which border you talking about..? http://jsfiddle.net/PQVnT/4/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are talking about the dotted line in Firefox, I think what you're looking for is this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }
```

This is a thread on the topic: [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Answer (score 27):

Use either of these CSS Styles

```css
a:active,
a:focus,
input,
input:active,
input:focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
}  
a:active,
a:focus,
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

OR

```css
:focus {outline:none;} ::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Once the CSS Style part is done, then you might also need to set the IE-Emulator. Update your web applications web.config file and include below key.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <clear />
      <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=7; IE=9; IE=8; IE=5;" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>

</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
outline: none;
```

This worked for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

Please don't remove the outlines on focus-styles, this makes your site less accessible to your keyboard-only and low-vision users.

If you choose to add something like `:focus { outline: none; }` to your stylesheets, also add you owns styles for focused elements.

Reading: [Never remove CSS outlines](http://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/)

Answer (score 2):

It's an outline.
Use `outline:none;` on :focus pseudo-class to remove it.
Worked well for me.