# remove only border bottom of the button after clicking

Tags: html, css, angularjs

i want to remove the bottom border of a button after clicking it. button is not a submit button. When i click it for the second time, the border should be 1px; Can some one help me with implementing this

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and describe why it's not working for you?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4524180/unwanted-outline-or-border-around-button-when-clicked

Comment: You are going to want some javascript onclick events tied to your button element. The JS will have to test the number of times it has been click on, and change the class associated with the button element.

Comment: guys try to not disappoint developers, you are here not to make them look stupid, Meena, put your code in order to get help, and read about how to write a question in Stackoverflow in order to get help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 button it should be as simple as this:

## Angular for Single Button

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
  $scope.hideBorder = false;
  $scope.toggleBorder = function () {
    $scope.hideBorder = !$scope.hideBorder;

  }
}]);
```

## HTML for Single Button

```
<button class="{{hideBorder ? 'button--no-bottom-border': ''}}" ng-click="toggleBorder()">Click Me</button>
```

## CSS

```
button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none;
}
.button--no-bottom-border {
  border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

If you have multiple buttons, your Angular & HTML will change slightly:

## Angular for Multiple Buttons

```
$scope.toggleBorder = function (button) {
    button.hideBorder = !button.hideBorder;
  }
$scope.buttons = [
  {
    text: "Click Me",
    hideBorder: false
  },
  {
    text: "Click Me 2",
    hideBorder: false
  },
  {
    text: "Click Me 3",
    hideBorder: false
  },
];
```

## HTML for Multiple Buttons

```
<button class="{{button.hideBorder ? 'button--no-bottom-border': ''}}" ng-click="toggleBorder(button)" ng-repeat="button in buttons">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.This is what i wanted. It works perfectly fine :)

Comment: No problem! If this answer was helpful to you, make sure to mark it as accepted so it can be of benefit to others as well.