# Totally invisible html buttons

Tags: html, button, input, visibility, invisible

Use the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="submit" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;">
</body>
</html>
```

Save this file as a html file. If you open the file there is an invisible but still active button.
Press Tab to select the button. Now there is a grey dotted rectangle arround the still invisible button. Can someone help me to disable that rectangle. Thanks to responders
I'm trying to make a totally invisible site login, that's the only visible part of it, please help.

Comment: That's the browser's way of letting you know which control has the focus.  I don't think it can be disabled via HTML.

Comment: Perhaps some more information about your use case would help?

Comment: Maybe you should post a question about what you are trying to do and see what ideas people have about other ways to accomplish whatever is it you are attempting.

Comment: If you want to hide the submit button, just use display: none; If that won't do, provide more info what you're trying to accomplish, as IHateATMFees says.

Comment: You won't see that rectangle on a touch-only device, like an iPhone.  Because the browser decided it isn't needed.

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this... in case you don't want to use it for anything dodgy, and say, you want to make a default action if user presses the enter key, use a framework like jQuery and listen to keypresses. Or just try to redesign your UI properly.

Comment: More info on what you are trying to accomplish would be good. This is bad practice on so many levels, there is likely a better way to do it, unless you are indeed trying to deceive visitors.

Comment: With no explanation, it sounds like you are doing something I wouldn't want to help with.

Comment: **DUDES, I'VE READ THE COMMENTS, I'M NOT ILLEGAL OR SOMETHING!!!**

Comment: @VVWdefect If you ask a question for which the obvious application is something illegal, and don't provide an explanation for why what your doing isn't illegal, then I will assume that what your doing is illegal. It's not like I'm going to call the police - I'm just not going to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Answer (score 20):

You can use the style `outline: 0;` to disable the dotted rectangle from the button when it's focused.

**Example:**

```
<input type="submit" style="outline: 0;">
```

Though, I'm not sure what you are trying to do is correct... Are you just trying to hide the button? Your best bet is to use `display: none;`

**Example:**

```
<input type="submit" style="display: none;">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/AHsdJ/ No, it looks like they are trying to make the submit button for a form clickable without someone's knowledge it's there.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me. (Only tested on Opera so YMMV).

```
<input type="submit" style="background:transparent; border:none; color:transparent;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AHsdJ/3/

Comment: This worked for me too. I think it's best to use a combination of `outline` and `border`. E.g. `background-color:transparent; color:transparent; outline:none; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border:none;`

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS :focus & :active pseudo-classes

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
input:focus, input:active { outline: none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it transparent as you what did, and then make the button disabled. This works perfectly for me.

```
<input type="submit" style="color: transparent; background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent; cursor: default;" disabled>
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use a button at all.

Use AJAX to send login data via post and handle the response within your page.