# Get rid of dotted line around for input type image?

Tags: html, css

I've tried doing this a bunch of different ways. Nothing seems to work.  What am I missing here?

HTML code:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"     method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="someval">
<input type="image" src="Btn.PNG" border="0" 
    name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/WEBSCR-640-20110401-    1/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Tried Javascript:

```
function NoLinkBorder()
{
    var links = document.getElementById('noborder').getElementsByTagName('a');
    for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) 
    {
        links[i].onmousedown = function () 
        {
            this.blur();
            return false;
        }
        links[i].onclick = function() 
        {
            this.blur();
        }
        if ( /msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/opera/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) 
        {
            links[i].onfocus = function() 
            {
                this.blur();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes I used the right id tag

I tried a couple differenet css techniques. One wraping the form in a div:

```
.MoneyButton {     
    background:url(Btn.PNG) no-repeat;     
    cursor:pointer;     
    border: none; 
}


div.MoneyButton input { 
    background:url(Btn.PNG) no-repeat; 
    width: 534px;     
    height: 260px;     
    border: none; 
}
```

also tried a simple css technique:

```
a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

and

```
a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Nothing seems to work.  the dotted line still shows up around the image/form when clicked in IE 8.

any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links

Comment: how did you get the html to show up Luzhin? When I first posted this it was invisible.  tried putting the 4 spaces in front of each line and leaving no space as well.  I would like to follow the style guidelines here.

Comment: You need to indent each line of code with four spaces like you did with your JS and CSS.

Comment: I did that, though... Well technically, I did that, but saw it wasn't showing up in the 'preview panel' underneath, So I highlighted it all and click on the HTML button at the top of the text area.

Answer (score 4):

`<input type="image">` is of type `input`, which is why the outline style isn't applying to it.

Remove the `a` from your focus style so it applies to *any* elements in focus, not just `a` elements:

```
:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to only remove the outline from inputs of type image, use input[type=image]:focus{outline:none;}

Comment: HOLY COW! it's that easy?!   I didnt even know you could do that in CSS, I mean, :whatever instead of a:whatever.  what does that mean? Does that mean its applied to every html element?

Comment: @SlickRick: Yup. You know how you can use `#id` and `.class` alone? The same goes for `:pseudoclass` - applies to any kind of element with that ID/class/pseudo-class.

Comment: Strange that didn't work for me. I'm still getting dotted lines on my buttons.