# Html "select" position on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've got a select in my site. With the following:

```
...
<select name="opening-form-gender" id="opening-form-gender">
    <option value="f">Female</option>
    <option value="e">Male</option>
</select>
...
```

CSS:

```
#opening-form {
  background-image: url('../img/opening-form-bg.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 139px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
#opening-form p {
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#666666;
}
#opening-form strong {
    font-size:20px;
}

#opening-form .submit {
  background-image: url('../img/red-submit.png');
  border: none;
  width: 115px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
#opening-form .submit:hover {
  background-image: url('../img/red-submit-hover.png');
}
```

So, its have a style problem. How can i fix it?

This is jsfiddle page:

http://jsfiddle.net/HLEcS/

Comment: Post some css styles for a select, or live demo on jsfiddle please

Comment: @goliney sorry, edited my post.

Comment: Is that normal you've got `#opening-form-gender` in your HTML, and `#opening-form` in your CSS ?

Comment: @samsamX please see jsfiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like;

```
select{
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
  background-image: url('../img/input-bg.png');
  font-weight: regular;
  font-size:12px;
  color: #666666;
  padding: 7px;
}
```

***[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/HLEcS/2/)*** is the modified fiddle.

Comment: +1. Problem is default select css options. So this is working well.

Answer (score 0):

On WebKit (Chrome, Safari), you can disable the native style and customize it with your own by applying the property:

`-webkit-appearance: none;`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Gecko (Firefox). See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649849

The dotted border on Firefox is caused by the default property `outline`. See [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

The alignement should be fixed by applying a `vertical-align: top` to the parent. Please provide the full HTML or a Fiddle to test.

Comment: Yep, so I was wrong, you have to apply the `vertical-align:top` to the inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/HLEcS/1/

Comment: I cannot vote up to you but very very thank you. Helpful answer. Simple problem, when add vertical-align:top, text show on top.