# Disable DIV selection when clicking on it

Tags: html, css

How can i avoid selecting a div and hide the highlight when i click in it?
I want to hide the dotted outline:
[image: here's a screenshot if what i want to hide]

(can't get the screenshot to appear, here it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OKaP.png)

Comment: failed to get the image to show, but guess the description was enough.  thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use`outline:none` or `outline:0`

Check the similar one [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195081/how-to-remove-the-dotted-line-around-the-clicked-a-element-in-html/13195091#13195091)

Answer (score 16):

it can be done with a css class . 
like .if this is your div :

```
<div class='disableSelection'>text</div>
```

then apply this css .

```
<style>
.disableSelection{
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
outline: 0;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked in my case:

element {

-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

}

as per 
[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color)

Answer (score 2):

Add `outline:0;` to your `div`.

I usually see this problem on IE more than other browsers.

Ref [**here**](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/) for more info:

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but check [Chris Coyers article (Removing The Dotted Outline) on this](http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/)

But think about the usability issues if you don't set an alternative active state at all. But I guess Chris is mentioning this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
*:focus{outline:none}
```

- **please add this code in your css file. This is css issue**

Answer (score 0):

Very important to add "a", to say you are adding it for a link:

```
<style>
.disableSelection a {
outline: 0;
}
</style>
```