# Is there a difference between "outline: none" and "outline: 0"?

Tags: css, outline

I was reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13195081/5620297) on disabling the dashed borders around `<a>` links. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195091/5620297) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195231/5620297) used `outline: none`, while [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13195127/5620297) used `outline: 0`

Is there any difference between using `outline: none` and `outline: 0`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline):

> The CSS `outline` property is a shorthand property for setting one or more of the individual outline properties `outline-style`, `outline-width` and `outline-color` in a single declaration

So when you set `outline` to `none` or `0`, you are actually telling the browser to set 3 properties (`outline-style`, `outline-width` and `outline-color`)

I used Firefox Developer Tools to find out the difference:

[image: <code>outline: 0</code>]
[image: <code>outline: none</code>]

As you can see, they both use the default text color as the `outline-color`, and they both have `outline-style` set to `none`. The only difference is the `outline-width`:

- When the `outline` is `0`, the `outline-width` is `0px`
- When the `outline` is `none`, the `outline-width` is `medium`

That is the only difference between the two. You can use either one, they will both display the same way (since the `outline-style` is `none`, it does not matter how wide the outline is).

Comment: Also, when you want to remove borders. The most common way is `border:0;`. Like outline, border is shorthand for several properties. So I'd go with `outline:0;`

Comment: @TomKentell Me too, I would go with `outline: 0`