# Remove input blue outline color

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using an input component and trying to remove the outline blue default color, but everything I tried failed

I already tried to change the CSS focus outline and box-shadow attributes

```
:focus {
  outline: 0px !important;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  box-shadow: none !important
}
```

I expect the blue outline to disappear when focused on the input component

[input outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQTmA.png)

Comment: have you tried `outline:none`: https://jsfiddle.net/axmfkqLg/1/.  If that doesn't work then you need to create a [mcve] as you probaby have other styles conflicting

Comment: I tried it, I will look for a conflict CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648667/outline-none-vs-outline-0)

> The outline CSS property is a shorthand to set various outline properties in a single declaration: outline-style, outline-width, and outline-color.

So when we set outline to `none` or `0`, we are actually setting 3 properties

- outline-style
- outline-width
- outline-color

This is obtain from chrome developer options:

`outline:none;` will set:

```
outline-color: initial;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: initial;
```

`outline:0;` will set:

```
outline-color: initial;
outline-style: initial;
outline-width: 0px;
```

In your case setting **`outline:none`** should do a trick.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding!!!

Answer (score 4):

This border is used to show that the element is focused. You can remove it, though:

```
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

You may want to add some other way for users to know what element has keyboard focus though for usability.

Chrome will also apply to highlight to other elements such as DIV's used as modals. To prevent the highlight on those and all other elements as well, you can do:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input />
</div>
<div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add this (no need for the `:focus` selector)-:

```
input{
  outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting ? you can remove it by using `outline:none`
And you can add other color to it by giving the color as border.

```css
input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to suggest a solution with out checking the code where issue is reproducible. Even it looks like an outline, it can the implemented as a `border`, `box-shadow` or something else. for example, in bootstrap, there is a thick light blue border on `:focus` of the form elements and they are actually `box-shadow`.

So you inspect your element and its pseudo classes like `:hover`, `:focus`, `:active` etc and find out exactly what makes the blue border effect and then overwrite that particular style with your own style.