# HTML button becomes "selected" with little blue outline after it is clicked which is not needed to be

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what happening. I have a simple button in HTML with a simple action in JS.

Button in HTML:

```
<button class="btn_open_calc">Open Culculator</button>
```

Styles in CSS:

```
.btn_open_calc {
  background-color: rgb(232, 209, 237);
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: medium;
}
```

Response in main.js:

```
var btn_Open_Calc = document.querySelector('.btn_open_calc');
btn_Open_Calc.addEventListener("click", funcOpenCalc);

function funcOpenCalc() {
  Modal_Container.style.display = 'flex';
}
```

But when I press the button here is how it starts to look: 
[image]

When I press on any other place it disappears. But I want to get rid of it at all so it won't appear.

Comment: The focus marker is important. Not everybody chooses to or is capable of using a pointing device to interact with a document.

Comment: @Quentin It's not simple focus outline? (solve with `outline:none;` on focus css)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini — It **is** the focus marker. Getting rid of it harms accessibility. Don't do that.

Comment: Oh ok, and is possible so change 'color' to trasparency? so as not to remove it but simply hide it?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini — Making it invisible will cause the same accessibility problems that removing it will. People have to be able to see it in order to know where it is!

Comment: Oh ok i understand, thanks for the clarification

Comment: Maybe leave the focus indicator, and fix the spelling of “Culculator” instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `outline: none;` or `outline: 0;`([outline 0 vs none difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35648667/17447)) to the button's `css` to remove the outline.

---

But as [MDN notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline#Accessibility_concerns),

> #### Accessibility concerns
>
> Assigning outline a value of 0 or none will remove the browser's
>   default focus style. If an element can be interacted with, it must
>   have a visible focus indicator. Provide obvious focus styling if the
>   default focus style is removed.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to let others know that I'm not trippin' :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your CSS to get rid of it if you really want.

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

example:

```js
var btn_Open_Calc = document.querySelector('.btn_open_calc'); 
btn_Open_Calc.addEventListener("click", funcOpenCalc); 
function funcOpenCalc(){ 
Modal_Container.style.display = 'flex'; 
}
```

```css
.btn_open_calc{ 
background-color: rgb(232, 209, 237); 
width: 200px; height: 40px; 
border-radius: 10px; 
font-size: medium; 
}

button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button  class="btn_open_calc">Open Culculator</button>
```

Comment: Everything under your CSS in redundant. The simple answer is: `outline: none`.

Comment: Which is exactly why I said "example" afterwords in which I used OP's code to show it works with what he wants.

Comment: Why would you post a full-blown example including JS to explain the CSS?

Comment: Because it is exactly what the OP posted as his code and I'm showing him it working in his environment.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. If I could accept both yours and upper answer I would have done it. But I can't. So many thanks and good luck.