# Dotted border around link?

Tags: html, css

After having read all dotted border questions possible, and not having found an answer, I write my question below.

How do i remove the dotted border around the div when i click on a link inside it?

[This image shows the word "photography", which has a dotted border when clicked on.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zKKf.png)

The basics behind this is just a dropdown, that appears when that section is clicked on, which works absolutely fine, i just cannot stand that border, does my nut in.

Any ideas?

Comment: set `CSS` property of your div to `outline: none`.

Comment: already tried css property and inline styles, it was mentioned in lots of questions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195081/how-to-remove-the-dotted-line-around-the-clicked-a-element-in-html

Comment: @E.Nunn could you provide the code you've tried?

Comment: Share your tried code first @E.Nunn

Comment: If you *must* remove the focus ring, please read and follow the instructions at https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/ to ensure that you do not break your site for keyboard-only users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `focus` state. Try to add this:

```
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Or if that element isn't a real link, but for example just an `li`, make that

```
li:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thankyou at last. I'm using WordPress with the Avada theme, and all you need to do is add this to the Custom CSS area.

    a:focus { 
       outline: none !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use below css property.

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Please read this article - https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/  and http://www.outlinenone.com/ for more clarification