# How to remove the dotted white border around focused button text

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need to, but cannot, remove the white dotted border around the text of a focused button.

After reading articles about "remove white border (especially [Dotted border around link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532455/dotted-border-around-link) and links inside), I have try several solutions of disabling outline like `"outline: 0;` or `outline: none;`, using or not `!important`.

But nothing does remove the dotted white border around the text of a focused button.
Here is my simplest test page code. I cannot show a screenshot, because it removes the focus from the button.

```css
button {
  font-size: 87.5%;
  font-family: "ubuntu", Sans-serif;
  padding: 0 16px;
  min-width: 64px;
  height: 36px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  outline: none;
  outline: 0;
  outline: none !important;
  outline: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">TEST</button>
```

Using Firefox 67.0.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), this page still shows a dotted white border around focused button text, which I'd like to remove (I'll show the focus with a method of my own).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These styles are declared at the UA level, so each browser has their own implementation (and in Firefox case, pseudo elements for targeting them).

In Firefox, you can use the `::-moz-focus-inner` pseudo element:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Another useful information: In IE6 the dotted line cannot be removed unless this meta tag is added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />`

Comment: Thank you Adrift,
It perfectly does the job.
Because of "-moz-", I suppose that "focus-inner" is a mozilla-only property.
Where could I get the similar info for the other major browsers (IE, Chrome (Chromium), Opera, Safar

Comment: @adrift : the funny point is that even mdm web docs (aka mozilla devs docs) doesn't know "::-moz-focus-inner" pseudo selector ...

Comment: @adrift, for my button, button::-moz-focus-inner alone functions but input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add setback for different browsers, for example:

```
button:focus,
button:active {
    -moz-outline: 0;
    -ms-outline:0;
    -o-outline: 0;
    -webkit-outline: 0;
}
```

These are the vendor-prefixed properties offered by the relevant rendering engines (-webkit for Chrome, Safari; -moz for Firefox, -o for Opera, -ms for Internet Explorer). Typically they're used to implement new, or proprietary CSS features, prior to final clarification/definition by the W3.

Answer (score 0):

Just set border: 0 , I have updated your code try this it will work!

```
 <input type="button" value="text">
```

And in style tag just use this:-

```
 input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
            border: 0
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Ronack,
I have install this and it does function.
Unfortunately, my pages are expected to be online one next day ...
Where could I get the same info for the other major browsers (IE, Chrome (Chromium), Opera, Safari, ...) ?

Comment: Thank you Kiranvj, I yet use prefixFree, witch purpose seams the same.

Comment: How  can I check that "::-webkit-focus-inner" and "::-o-focus-inner" and so on, will have the same influence in the other browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

`a::-moz-focus-inner` did not work for me in a situation where a React Router redirect was inexplainably causing focus borders. The selector itself did not activate.

Temporarily solved with (but not happy with):

```
a::-moz-focusring {
  outline: none;
}
```