# blue outline in slider dots- owl carousel2.3.4

Tags: css, owl-carousel

I am trying to remove the blue outline that shows up when clicking on the dots in the slider, I looked in Owl carousel documentation and scoured the web but couldn't find anything substantial, can someone please help me resolve this

here is the codepen
[Owl Carousel Dots](https://codepen.io/sabarishraj88/pen/oQYmVm)

```
$(function() {
    $("#team-members").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        smartSpeed: 700,
        items: 3,
        loop: true

    });

});
```

Comment: That would be it including states `.owl-dot, .owl-dot:active, .owl-dot:focus { outline: 0; }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to remove the dotted line around the clicked a element in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195081/how-to-remove-the-dotted-line-around-the-clicked-a-element-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

you just need **outline:none**

```
.owl-theme .owl-dots .owl-dot {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button:focus { outline: 0}
```

This will fix it.