# How to remove the button outline in Firefox 17.0.1

Tags: css, firefox, button, twitter-bootstrap, outline

For aesthetics reasons (I know this affects accessibility) I want to remove the `outline` in some buttons, but in Firefox 17.0.1 I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I tried the answers in [**this popular question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links) but none of them worked.

Here's a jsfiddle with an example of the buttons, http://jsfiddle.net/t54JE/ when you click the buttons you can see the outline (using Firefox 17 of course).

or maybe this is a bug with FF? they don't want us to remove the outline?

Comment: Firefox 17.0.1 (and earlier up to v.15) on OSX doesn't have any outline.

Comment: To be exact, it's actually a Bootstrap style that's being applied. Remove the Bootstrap includes and there's no outline: http://jsfiddle.net/t54JE/13/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS from the question you linked works perfectly:

```
.btn:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

See the following JSFiddle for the CSS in action: http://jsfiddle.net/t54JE/12/