# Remove outline of <html> when tab in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, tabs, outline

http://i45.tinypic.com/34pezdj.jpg

The outline appears when tab through all element in the web.
This happen only in Firefox (not appear in Chrome, Opera, Safari)

I use Firebug console to detect what element is on focus by: document.activeElement then it shows

```
>>> document.activeElement

<html>
```

Then tried:

```
html {outline: 0}
```

But this outline still appear.

How can we get rid of this one?

p.s: I try tab through all page of other pages like Google, Facebook. There is no outline like this.

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution

```
:focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Comment: Please do not duplicate answers across questions.

Comment: ohh... i just trying to help people so that they easily find their solution

Comment: If you want to make it easier, just mark a question as a duplicate of the question with the canonical answer. Once you reach 3k reputation, you can [vote to close questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as a duplicate of another. If you do not have that amount of reputation, just post a comment on the question, e.g. `Related: [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Seems like there was some confusion here, so I shall correct myself:

**Since there is no other element than `<body>`, FF can only focus `<body>`**, thus the dotted line around it. ([screenshot](http://oi45.tinypic.com/34pezdj.jpg))

Try to add an element / elements to body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='haha.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" title="">I'm an example.</a>
        <a href="#" title="">Me too.</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, you can cycle focus through the elements by pressing the tab key and you should see that dotted line moving to the active element.

**ORIGINAL POST**

You're probably looking for `border` instead.

```
html {
    border: none;
}
```

Depending on the other css on the page, you might have to do this:

```
html, body {
    border: none;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is there a style attribute applied to body?

Comment: There is no other style. Here are the files
test.html:
[    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head> 
         <link rel='stylesheet' href='haha.css'>
    </head>
    <body>   
    </body>
    </html>
]
haha.css:
[    html, body {
        border: none;
        outline: 0;
    }]

Comment: hmm, when I keep on tabbing, the outline around the page still appears.
http://i45.tinypic.com/20uwigw.jpg

Comment: because it's a built-in feature in browsers. you won't get rid of it. and even of you could disable it, you shoul not do that: the user expects that line to show him where the focus is. if it's not there anymore: bad. http://www.spotlessinteractive.com/articles/usability-research/usability-user-behaviours/user-expectations-are-important.php.