# Remove Focus Outline from Input type="range" in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, focus, outline

I know there are other questions like this but I've tried everything they have suggested to no avail. This is a different question than [Remove dotted outline from range input element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794026/remove-dotted-outline-from-range-input-element-in-firefox) as I'm asking what is causing this rogue outline - the previous question answers how to get the colored outlines shown below.

This SO question ([Remove dotted outline from range input element in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794026/remove-dotted-outline-from-range-input-element-in-firefox)) mentions the firefox bug - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=932410 but it has since been marked as resolved but I'm still having this issue.

The input CSS is:

```
input[type=range]:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 1px solid orange;
}
input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: 1px solid green;
}

input[type=range] {
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-thumb {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
input[type=range]:focus::-moz-range-track {
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
input[type='range']::-moz-focus-inner {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

The computed CSS from my browser is:

[image]

The rendered input in the browser looks like this:

[image]

From my testing it looks like `:-moz-focusring` and `:focus` are the same property - green outline, overwrites the orange.

`-moz-appearance: none;` on the element does nothing along with `::-moz-focus-inner`.

You can see the range-thumb has a red border and range-track has a blue border but there is still the dotted outline. I tried the 'hide it behind a border' trick from the 2nd answer in the above SO question but then the white border is on top of the range-thumb like the dotted outline is in the picture. The outline-offset also does not extend on the left or right so the dotted lines on the end still show.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In the future, it would be best to link to a working example instead a of just images of the problem. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: If there is a new answer, it should be posted as an answer to the old question. We do not want to have copies of the same question around, with different sets of answers.

Comment: @PatrickM thanks, I wish I could, can't because of my client.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I will repost my question in the previously mentioned question, thanks.

Answer (score 18):

input[type='range']::-moz-focus-outer { border: 0; }