# Overriding the dotted outline in firefox without using '!important' declaration?

Tags: css, firefox, outline

When an element like a dropdown menu or link is clicked, Firefox shows a dotted outline. I see that it acts as an important visual indicator for keyboard-based navigation (among others), but in my case (a news website), there are so many links in the navbar that it'd make keyboard navigation, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd> ..., quite painful and unrealistic (i.e. why'd anyone want to press a key that many times when they can simply use a mouse instead?) and so, I want to remove it.

---

***EDIT:*** As for accessibility... since I am using something like `ELEMENT:focus { border: 2px solid #359; }` for menus, `text-decoration: underline;` for links, etc. my website is accessible via keyboard as well. For example, it looks like this upon pressing tabs multiple times (call it an unintended side effect!):

[image: Keyboard accessibility - visual indicator]

---

Upon searching, I found out [a simple way to remove the outline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844452):

```
:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
}

::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0 !important;
}
```

**EDIT:** This is added at the top of the stylesheet that's loaded right after [Twitter Bootstrap CSS](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css).

I needed to use the `!important` declaration as the cascading didn't work, i.e. I tried this and it didn't work:

```
*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

*::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I am after through cascading and not having to use `!important` or defining specific elements (e.g. `a:focus`, `button:focus`...)?

If the answer is no, is there a specific set of elements that Firefox does this to? If so, what are they? (`<a>` for sure.)

Comment: *i.e. why'd anyone want to press a key that many times when they can simply use a mouse instead?* ... simple: some people have physical disabilities that prevent them from using a mouse. It's called **Accessibility**, and it's an important topic to be aware of for web developers. (hint: some countries/states have legal requirements for website accessibility)

Comment: @Spudley Okay, thanks for the heads up. My site does have clear visual indicators to make it accessible via keyboard as well (it's just that I initially *felt* that it's not realistic to use keyboard). I've edited my question to reflect the same. Please take a look.

Comment: I believe !important is in the bootstrap file, so remove them and your code should work if it is included after the bootstrap css

Comment: @Adam As I see it that's not the case.