# How do i remove the blue outline from a radio box when focused?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, radio-button

I would like to remove the blue outline it gives me when my radio is clicked/focused.
I tried using `outline: none` and `border: none`, but nothing seems to be working.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Screenshot of what I’m talking about:

[image]

Comment: Where do you see a blue outline? Are you talking about Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes, in google Chrome, whenever i click on the radio checkbox it gives me a square blue outline around it, and i want to get rid of it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20593224/remove-blue-selected-outline-on-buttons

Comment: Can you show us your CSS and the HTML you are referencing it in? The flagged duplicate has outline: none as a solution, which you already state you've tried.

Answer (score 9):

Remove the outline when the input element has the focus.

```
input:focus{
  outline:none;
}
```

As a side note, this is only for Google Chrome, other browsers use different techniques for showing an input element has the focus.

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, I tried this already, and it doesn't work somehow.

Comment: @The301 please create a basic demo so we could inspect it. you can create one on jsFiddle

Comment: Provided a screenshot, i'm pretty sure you guys know what i mean now.

Comment: We know what you meant before this, but we need code if the listed solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE:

Having worked a lot with accessibility lately, I've come to understand that removing the outline from inputs is not a very good thing. It prevents people using keyboard navigation to see what's focused.

---

ORG POST:

You might have to be more specific with your selector. When using bootstrap you have to override it (in my version, 3.3.6 at least) by selecting input[type="radio"]:focus, not just input:focus, like this:

```
input[type="radio"]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a separate issue, but I had to set box-shadow to none as well.

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks , adding   box-shadow: none; solves the issue

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but hope that it helps somebody!

```
input[type='radio']:focus {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
/*For Bootstrap*/
.custom-control-input:focus ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```css
input[type="radio"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input[type=radio] {
    outline-color: transparent; 
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: box-shadow: none