# How to remove the blue box shadow border in button if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to do is remove the button blue box shadow effect in my class `btnd` if the button is click.

current [output](http://jsfiddle.net/6VrXD/38/):

i tried this but it doesnt work.

```
.btnd:active,
.btnd.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Just add `outline: 0;` for `.btnd:focus` as explained here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome#answer-21758143

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Blue shadow is browser default :focus state

```
.btnd:active,
.btnd:focus,
.btnd:focus:active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Although this answer is technically correct, I am surprised that no one has mentioned that removing the outline is not recommended for accessibility reasons. See http://www.outlinenone.com/ or https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/.

Answer (score 29):

I deal with this problem just yesterday. You need:

```
.btnd:focus, .btnd:active, .btnd.active, .btnd:focus:active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

The key is in last selector `.btnd:focus:active`.

Comment: The .btnd:focus:active prevents the outline that appears for a split second when clicked. +1, well done

Answer (score 0):

just use this line to remove the focus
$( "#OK" ).button().blur();