# How to remove button border when press

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I am having problem of removing button's border when clicking
I use border:none but doesn't work
I put border-radius to my button , but when I click there is a border that appears
in square how to remove this?

here is my image Thanks in advance..

here is my css

```
.putadditionalitem{
    width:49%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Poplar Std;
    color:#fff;
    background: #05f11b;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #05f11b, #0bbb1c);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #05f11b, #0bbb1c);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #05f11b, #0bbb1c);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #05f11b, #0bbb1c);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #05f11b, #0bbb1c); 
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Post your code here?

Comment: Better post your css, html and jquery code

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)

Comment: You need to have a look @ CSS outline (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) but you also need to keep in mind this is used for accesibility also.

Answer (score 6):

It's not the border that does that, it's the outline.

Use

```
outline:none;
```

and that will fix it.

Here's an example:

```css
.no-outline {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<input type='text'>
<br><br>
<input type='text' class='no-outline'>
```

The first `input` has a blue outline around it on `:focus`, the second one doesn't.

Comment: YES! that is what I am looking for by the way is my question so easy?

Comment: It's a simple question, but it's a valid one :) @BrandonJakeSullano

Comment: I will accept your answer tomorrow hehe it it says you can accept answer after 7 minutes then I need to go :) THANKS!

Comment: OK no worries, glad I could help! @BrandonJakeSullano