# Integrating a 'hamburger' with a navigation menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working hamburger. And I have a working menu.

Can anyone integrate the two?

When I click on the hamburger, I want my menu with fade-in to appear.

When clicked again, I want my menu to fade out.

My two pieces of code are below (By the way, I am not very fluent in coding).

Thanks.

---

Hamburger

```
<style>

.buttons-container {
  margin: 100px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

button {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0.5em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
button span {
  display: block;
}

.grid-button {
  padding: 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.grid-button .grid {
  width: 0.5rem;
  height: 0.5rem;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  /* Not in use when the colors are specified below */
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.grid-button.close .grid {
  -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg) scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
  transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -45deg) scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}

.grid-button.rearrange .grid {
  box-shadow: -0.625rem -0.625rem, 0 -0.625rem, 0.625rem -0.625rem, -0.625rem 0, 0.625rem 0, -0.625rem 0.625rem, 0 0.625rem, 0.625rem 0.625rem;
}

.grid-button.rearrange.close .grid {
  box-shadow: 0 -0.5rem, 0 -1rem, 0.5rem 0, -1rem 0, 1rem 0, -0.5rem 0, 0 1rem, 0 1rem;
}

.grid-button.collapse .grid {
  box-shadow: -0.625rem 0, -0.625rem 0.625rem, 0.625rem 0, 0.625rem -0.625rem, 0 -0.625rem, -0.625rem -0.625rem, 0 0.625rem, 0.625rem 0.625rem;
}

.grid-button.collapse.close .grid {
  box-shadow: -0.5rem 0, 0 0 transparent, 0.5rem 0, 0 0 transparent, 0 -0.5rem, 0 0 transparent, 0 0.5rem, 0 0 transparent;
}

/* ====================== lines button ==================================================*/
.lines-button {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  transition: .3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 0.285715rem;
  /* */
}
.lines-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.lines-button:active {
  transition: 0;
}

.lines {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 0.285715rem;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 0.142855rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: relative;
}
.lines:before, .lines:after {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 0.285715rem;
  background: #FF0000;
  border-radius: 0.142855rem;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0.142855rem center;
  transform-origin: 0.142855rem center;
}
.lines:before {
  top: 0.5rem;
}
.lines:after {
  top: -0.5rem;
}

.lines-button:hover .lines:before {
  top: 0.57143rem;
}
.lines-button:hover .lines:after {
  top: -.57143rem;
}

.lines-button.close {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
  transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
}

.lines-button.arrow.close .lines:before, .lines-button.arrow.close .lines:after {
  top: 0;
  width: 1.11111rem;
}

.lines-button.minus.close .lines:before, .lines-button.minus.close .lines:after {
  -webkit-transform: none;
  transform: none;
  top: 0;
  width: 2rem;
}

</style>



<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <meta name="description" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="js/libs/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="buttons-container">

        <button type="button" role="button" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" class="lines-button minus">
          <span class="lines"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
  </section>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  <script>
    var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('button');

    [].forEach.call(anchor, function(anchor){
      var open = false;
      anchor.onclick = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(!open){
          this.classList.add('close');
          open = true;
        }
        else{
          this.classList.remove('close');
          open = false;
        }
      }
    }); 
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Menu

```
<nav id="vertical-nav">
<ul>

<li class="fadeIn-1"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li class="fadeIn-2"><a href="#">1</a></li>

<li class="fadeIn-3"><a href="#">2</a></li>

<li class="fadeIn-4"><a href="#">3</a></li>

<li class="fadeIn-5"><a href="#">4</a></li>

<li class="fadeIn-6"><a href="#">5</a></li>

</ul>
</nav>

<style type="text/css">
#vertical-nav{width:220px;height:100%;display:block;margin:0;padding:0}

#vertical-nav ul{margin:0;padding:0;background:transparent;list-style:none;overflow:hidden}

#vertical-nav ul li{width:100%;display:block;background:transparent;text-align:left;padding:0;overflow:hidden;padding:0;margin:0;border-bottom:0px solid #}

#vertical-nav ul li:last-child{border-bottom:0}/* border bottom removed on the last item */

#vertical-nav ul li a {position:relative;box-sizing:border-box;display:block;background:transparent;text-decoration:none;padding:4px 10px;font:14px Arial, sans-serif;color:#B3B3B3;background:transparent}

#vertical-nav ul li a:hover{color:#FF0000; padding: 4px 30PX}

#vertical-nav ul li a:hover:before{display:block;position:absolute;left:10px;top:8px;content:"";width:3px;height:9px;background:#FF0000}

-webkit-transition: {0.3s all;-moz-transition: 0.3s all;transition: 0.3s all}

.fadeIn-1 {
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
.fadeIn-2 {
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
.fadeIn-3{
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
.fadeIn-4{
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
.fadeIn-5{
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
.fadeIn-6{
-webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
-o-animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
animation:fadeIn ease-in 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@-o-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
@keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

</style>
```

Comment: Can you please create a working fiddle?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/my3qsbbv/

Comment: Did you properly create that fiddle or did you just copy and paste your code in?

Comment: I pasted the HTML and CSS into their proper fields. Was there something else I was supposed to do?

Comment: You didn't format it correctly, you left the <style> tags in the css stylesheet, and left the html tags where they were already automated.

Comment: You also forgot to include the external source for the javascript file, which you were linking to locally, please, if you require an answer, do your best to format your question properly.

Comment: Updated. Sorry...I'm new at this.

Comment: Can you send the updated link? The one sent previously is the same, you generated a new link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/LCfiddle/my3qsbbv/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/my3qsbbv/12/) is a fiddle of a working example of what you want.

I recreated your concept since your code was too long to read over simply. What you wanted was a button which when clicked a menu will fade in. I suggest you play around with the code and revamp it with your own.

This is the code I wrote.

HTML

```
<button id="shower" name="buttonOne">Show</button>

<div id="menu">
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>        
    </u>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

ul {
    padding:0;
}

#menu {
    display:none;
    animation:fadeIn 1s;
}

#buttonss {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
         opacity:1;   
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shower').click(function() {
        if( $("#menu").css('display') == 'block') {
            $('#menu').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $('#menu').css('display', 'block');         
        }       
    });
});
```

I hope this helped, I'm sure it won't be too much trouble to recreate your own styling within my concept, best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Samir. This helps a lot. I working on integrating now.

Comment: I hope it's the correct answer :D Good luck my friend :)

Comment: You're welcome! Could you mark the question as correct? Glad I could help! :) @user5336878

Comment: Samir. I will do that. Just how?

Comment: BTW, I am getting a blue halo around the menu in Chrome and Opera when clicked on. Any idea why?

Comment: Click the check under the voting widget to the left of my answer :) And I had the same problem, this was very useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome, glad I could help! :)