# Select the element with blue color

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Someone knows how disable this blue select?

Thanks

[Cames when use tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWGx5.png)

Comment: is it chrome? Some browsers has default behaviour for certain things ( i have seen that blue thing in chrome before ). Try to inspect the element and see what styles it.

Answer (score 0):

in your css:

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

ref: 
[Remove blue border from css custom-styled button in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)