# Remove blue border appearing around element when clicked

Tags: html, css

I'm using Firefox on Mac OS. When I CMND+CLICK the text in the table a blue border appears around the TD. Am I able to tell CSS to not show this border on click/focus?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello World!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blue border from css custom-styled button in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your CSS put

```
table {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You're likely encountering the `outline`. Try this:

```
td { outline: none; }  /* value "0" also works */
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline