# How to remove/hide the blue border line when someone click on a button

Tags: html

How do I hide the blue border in this picture? [Blue border button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq4jV.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove blue border from css custom-styled button in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add this to the CSS: `button:focus {outline:0;}`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of outline

Add this to your css

```css
a:hover,
a:active,
a:focus,
input:hover,
input:active,
input:focus,
button:hover,
button:active,
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code,

```
button:focus { 
  outline: none; 
}
```