# How do I stop browsers from automatically highlighting a button when it is clicked?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am trying to make a custom HTML button element, but chrome highlights it (like above) when it is clicked. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution(s) :-**

```
button:focus {
    /** Your CSS styles**/
}
button:active {
    /** Your CSS styles**/
}
```

**Explanation(s) :-**

```
The :focus selector is used to select the element that has focus.
Tip: The :focus selector is allowed on elements that accept keyboard events 
or other user inputs.

Browser Support
Chrome  Safari  Firefox Opera   IE  Android iOS
4+      3.1+    Any     9.6+    8+  Any     Any

The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.
A link becomes active when you click on it.
Tip: The :active selector can be used on all elements, not only links.

Browser Support
Chrome  Safari  Firefox Opera   IE  Android iOS
4+      3.1+    Any     9.6+    8+  Any     Any
```

Syntax ::

```
:focus {
    css declarations;
}
:active {
    css declarations;
}
```

**Notes And References :-**

[w3schools Reference (Focus Selector) ::](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp)

[w3schools Reference (Active Selector) ::](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp)

[Stack Overflow Solutions  ::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

G'day - this is the focus state of the button. You can style it as follows:

```
button:focus {
  outline: none;
  /** Any additional styles go here **/
}
```

For more information on focus take a look at this article from CSS tricks:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code**

```
a:visited {
    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

See the code for better understanding about button behavior... https://codepen.io/zakirbd/pen/wmxxGX

Comment: Codepen link returns a 404 error