# Setting a button border-radius makes for focus on click

Tags: html, css

I'm seeing some odd behaviour concerning standard HTML buttons on Chrome. A standard button does not add an outline when clicked; only on focus through keyboard.

```html
<button type="button">Works as expects</button>
```

As soon as I add styling with border-radius, the button will get an outline when clicked.

```html
<button type="button" style="border-radius: 5px;">Focus on click</button>
```

Does anyone know what makes the button behave this way? And how can I make sure that the outline only gets added on keyboard navigation using the border-radius?

Comment: This question has been discussed in detail here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome

Comment: The question you link to is about removing the outline all together, and its repercussions. I don't see anything about: 'As soon as I add styling with border-radius, the button will get an outline when clicked.'.

Answer (score 1):

In response to the first part of the question:
If you right click on the round button, click inspect, and click the computed tab you can see that by adding styling it has overridden the platform-native styling:

`-webkit-appearance: button;`

has changed to:

`-webkit-appearance: none;`

the button's background-color change (when you hold down click) is also lost.