# How to hidden the border of button in sweetalert2

Tags: sweetalert2

The border of button appears automatically. How to close it so that it will never appear? Thanks.
[The button in sweetalert2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQdgd.png)

Comment: Some actual code would be useful. The answer will be in the CSS styles for the button though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are talking about the outline of a focused button:

[image]

It's possible to remove that outline from buttons, but **PLEASE DO NOT DO THAT**.

**[There's a reason for that ugly outline!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298082/1331425)**

You're killing the **keyboard accessibility** of your app. People with vision disabilities, as well as keyboard-ninjas, will hate you for that.

SweetAlert2 authors were working hard to make that plugin accessible to all users, by removing buttons outline you simply ruin their effort.

Comment: Thanks for your help. And yes, you are right, I agree with that. But you know, user often makes unassailable and strange requirement...