# css why do i have border after clicking the button?

Tags: css, button

When I click the button, a border is shown. How can I remove this border and why is it there?

This is the CSS code:

```
.operator button {
margin: 3px;
/*height: 25px;
width: 25px;*/  
border-radius: 50%;
background-color: green;
border: none; 
font-size: 10px;
padding: 12px 12px;
border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
transition-duration: 1s;
text-align: center;
display: inline;
 }
```

[here is an image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysAi4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add `outline: 0;` on your `button:focus` :

```css
.operator button {
    margin: 3px;
    /*height: 25px;
    width: 25px;*/  
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: green;
    border: none; 
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 12px 12px;
    border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline;
}

.operator button:focus { outline: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="operator">
  <button>Test</button>
</div>
```

You might want to read this too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25298082/9718056

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me