# Multicolored line visible and disappears after zooming in and out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a very weird problem and the only way I can show you is with a picture. The user clicks the X and the word disappears. What is weird is that there is some multicolored line that stays. The weirdest part is it disappears if you zoom in and then out in your browser. For instance if you go from 100% to 95% and back it will completely disappear. 
[image]

Comment: This is a question that can't be answered. Show the code that created this behaviour and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Could it may be related to this, a focus/css thing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome ?