# How to remove an outline from HTML elements 'button' and 'img' when onload or clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

On load my page or click the button, for some reason html applies some border to the button.

[image]

```
<div class="like-dislike">
<button class="button-like-dislike" id="likebtn24">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<input class="input-like-dislike" id="likeinput24" value="0" name="">
<button class="button-like-dislike" id="dislikebtn24">
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
<input class="input-like-dislike" id="dislikeinput24" value="0" name="">
</div>
```

Comment: If you share the contents of the CSS classes referenced, perhaps it'll be easier to get help.

Comment: Thats probably an css outline.. look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340138/remove-blue-border-from-css-custom-styled-button-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to prevent that by setting the outline to 'none' inside the CSS.

### **OUTLINE**

```
button {
     outline: none;
}
```

Remember to still show the user that the button has successfully been clicked though with :hover or :active

### **HOVER**

```
button:hover {
     /*CSS*/
}
```

### **ACTIVE**

```
button:active {
     /*CSS*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if removing the outline fixes it. Although, you'll likely want some sort of way to indicate the button is selected/ highlighted for accessibility purposes, such as a slight change in color.

```
button:focus, button:hover{
    outline: none;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if its work for you,

```
.button-like-dislike:hover , .button-like-dislike:focus , .button-like-dislike:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

button `button className`{
outline: none;
}

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it