# Remove outline from button in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, border

I have a button that holds an image. It looks fine in chrome, and even in IE. But in firefox it leaves an ugly thick border around the button. I have tried *border:none;* in CSS but nothing seems to change.

[image: Firefox button]

My button code is:

```
<button id="next3"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proddown.jpg') ?>"</button>
```

I currently have no styles attached.
Any ideas how to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: posible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links?rq=1

Comment: Nope, not a duplicate. I actually saw that question and the answer did not work for me.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue here - http://jsfiddle.net/x67Tm/

Comment: That's the one. background:transparent; - Answer it and I will accept it. Thanks again for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you need to add `background:transparent` to the `button` element. Adding this, along side `border:none` should solve the problem, if not, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links).

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/p45gv/)

```
button {
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even every CSS code you have, it have to start with this:

```
* {
margin: 0 !important;
padding: 0 !important;
border: 0 !important;
}
```

it is everytime helpful.
And i hope it helps you.