# how to remove background corner of the button when button clicked

Tags: css

How to remove focus of the button when button onclick event occur using css.I have used css outline:0 none but it not work.I have also used border:none but it also not working.What can i do please suggest me.

```
.btnfst {
    border-radius: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    background-color:   #1E90FF;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;

    border-style:hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-image-repeat: stretch;
    background-image: url('images/btt.png');

     border: none;
     outline: 0 none;
    -moz-outline-style: none;    
}
```

Comment: can you please show your code using code snippet tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links).

Comment: I share my code please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are removing the outline on the button it self, not on the focus moment.

Try:

```
.btnfst:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

With this you are removing the focus when the focus is active.

https://jsfiddle.net/851egdsm/

Comment: It is not working.Is there any another way please help me

Comment: is my fiddle working? And which browser are you working?