# Remove outline of <a>/<button>

Tags: html, css

how can i quit this blue area of map image??
I use on hover, focus, active

outline:0;
outline:none;

But nah... dont work.
I use bootstrap, if that can help on any answer.

This is the image with error:
[link text](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmwwu3rmm02cbj9/Sin%20t%C3%ADtulo.png?dl=0)

Thx for da help.

Comment: Add Code, or create fiddle

Comment: can u add your code on fiddle

Comment: try adding this to your CSS..`a{text-decoration:none;}`

Comment: or add `img{border:none;}` to your css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap fail. 
Solved with ...

outline: 0 important!;

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will work, but I think it would:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

[See the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

[See the links](http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/remove-button-focus-outline-using-css/)