# How to remove th select box after button clicked?

Tags: html, button

```
<input type="button" id="AutoRefresh" value="Auto Refresh" onclick="toggleRefresh();"/>
```

Before Click:

[image: Before Click]

After Click:

[image: After Click]

How to prevent the button from being visually selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like..

```
/* Outline due to focus */
input[type="button"]:focus {
    outline: none !important;   
}
```

or..

```
/* Any outlines applied */
#AutoRefresh { 
    outline: none !important;
}
```

..in your CSS file / `<style>` tag, or whatever method of styling you apply.

For Firefox:

```
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {   
    border : 0px;
}
```

Comment: Actually I have tried `input[type="button"]:active:focus {
  outline: none;
}` But doesn't work.

Comment: Is it browser specific? Seen solutions like `#myButton:-moz-focusring {
  outline: 0px;
}` being thrown out there

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links) for instance