# How to remove focus rectangle from an html input/button?

Tags: html, css

I got this input button ( `type="button"` ) on my page:

[image: Button]

When I click on it there is an annoying focus rectangle around:

[image: Button with annoying focus]

**How can I remove that?**

Here is my code:

```css
/*Buttons/Inputs*/
                    
.runInput {
   border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
   background: #001cbd;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#148bfa), to(#001cbd));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #148bfa, #001cbd);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #148bfa, #001cbd);
   padding: 6.5px 13px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
   -moz-border-radius: 12px;
   border-radius: 12px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.runInput:hover {
   background: #001cbd;
   color: #d9d9d9;
   }
.runInput:active {
   background: #00046e;
   }
.runInput:focus {
   outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<input class="runInput" onclick="runCode();" type="button" value="Run">
```

I tried to add `outline: none;` to my CSS but it didn't work.

*Thanks in advance for your answers!*

**EDIT:** I changed the snippet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Comment: I tried clicking the button on the snippet and I didn't see the rectangle. I am using Chrome. What browser are you using? Might try out Barun's suggestion.

Comment: On which navigator do you experience your problem ? If it is Firefox, then the answer at the potential duplicate should solve your issue.

Comment: I am using Firefox, I will see this article, thanks

Comment: You were right, it was due to Firefox! I tried in another browser and  it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Just add:**

```
:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

It will works for all element.

Or

If you need only for this class then add

```
.runInput:focus {
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with `outline` but it must be referenced correctly.

```
.runInput:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

OR

```
.runInput:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

[JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/bdrd01zd/)