# Getting horrible focus effect on <button> on mobile/touch interface only

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

So I have a standard  implementation in a React app:

```
<button
   onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
   className="button--round">
   {buttonContent}
</button>
```

Strangely, the button looks fine in a laptop browser (clicking with mouse), but in Firefox on my Android phone, as soon as I touch the button, it gets a horrible dotted border (which stays until I touch elsewhere) - it looks like the "focus" behaviour (like pressing tab through the interface on a keyboard) like this:

[image: focus effect]

I've tried:

```
button:active,
button:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

With no improvement. I also searched the various "sticky hover" answers on here and disabled hover totally, with no effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)? `button::-moz-focus-inner { border: 0; }`

Comment: Perfect - that did it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `border` of the pseudo-element `-moz-focus-inner` to get rid of this behavior.

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```