# Using <img> only with a class but without attributes at all

Tags: html, css

I used to have this for a button:

```
<img class="left" src="<?php echo $this->webroot."img/arrowleft.png";?>" width="32" height="31" alt="Arrow left button" />
```

Now I want to use this:

```
<img class="left" />
```

Then with CSS I can put a background image, define the size of the button and do everything that I want 100% with CSS. But I was wondering if it is acceptable and according to proper HTML coding standards to have `<img>` simply with a class and with no properties at all.

Comment: CSS is for presentation. HTML is for content. If you have an img element and don't put a foreground image on it, then you're doing *something* wrong.

Comment: I think there would be no problem with the browser but..
Why don't you use a div or a button element?

Comment: For what it's worth, class _is_ an attribute.

Comment: @DanFarrell Interesting, you are right, in this case `class` is an attribute. My question should probably be if it is acceptable to use `<img>` without the `src` attribute.

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: It is a void element, true. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-img-element):

> The src attribute must be present, and must contain a valid non-empty URL potentially surrounded by spaces referencing a non-interactive, optionally animated, image resource that is neither paged nor scripted.

Comment: That documentation is for HTML5. I guess it should apply the same way for previous versions of HTML.

Comment: @JaimeMontoya — Previous versions of HTML are irrelevant unless you are writing for browsers from the last century.

Comment: In that case, your answer would be indisputable based on the official documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did instead was to use `<span>` elements:

```
<span class="left"></span>
<span class="right"></span>
```

Then I made them work as buttons with CSS by providing a background, corresponding size, etc. So I am using `<span>` instead of `<img>` and everything is behaving exactly the same way as before.

**UPDATE 1**

Following up with @sean's advice in the first comment to this answer, it happened what I thought that would happen:

[image]

See the border. Yes, I can remove the border with CSS but those default behaviors sometimes I do not like because what if in some browsers it looks fine without border but only some browsers add that border by default, and sometimes I do not know specifically which browsers add what, but in general I guess only the border should be the thing to worry about in terms of presentation and style.

**UPDATE 2**

Also, see the dotted lines on the left arrow button. Those appeared after I clicked the left arrow button and this only happens on Firefox. Fortunately, I could apply this answer that I found at [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links):

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: If they're buttons, you should use `button` elements instead of `span`.

Comment: Very important, semantics matter. I will do that. Thank you for the advice. I hope `<button>` does not bring some of the default behavior that browsers may give to it by default and that then I would need to manually remove with CSS, or `<button>` display that works in certain way in certain browser. But true, if it is a button I should use the `<button>` element.

Comment: @sean See UPDATE 1 in my answer. But it is fine, I can take care of that by using CSS.

Comment: Check out [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). It makes rendering pretty consistent across browsers. It won't remove the border, but it should make it so that your CSS override looks the same across browsers.

Comment: @sean I did not know about that tool. See UPDATE 2 in my answer for example, another difference I identified, this time only happening on Firefox.

Comment: Browser discrepancies will probably always be a challenge, but the best way to ensure a consistent experience for users across all browsers/devices is to use the most semantic element available for the job. Be sure to add in your own custom focus states if you remove a browser's default focus state—keyboard-only and other users rely on them to know which element they're currently focused on. A good read on the topic: https://www.viget.com/articles/managing-focus-styles-without-breaking-accessibility/. Good luck!