# Remove double outline on button and it's text inside

Tags: html, css, windows, firefox, outline

I have a `button` with a text inside of it. I styled the `outline` on the `:active` and `focus` state like in the snippet bellow. I have a strange behaviour on `firefox`: When I tab into the `button`, there is an `outline` around the `button` and a second one around the text inside the button (see screenshot below). I just get this strange issue on `firefox`. How can I fix this. The only answer on my question that I found was, to use `outline: none;`, but this is not what I want. I want an outline just around the `button`.

`outline` on `chrome` Windows 10:

[image]

`outline` on `firefox` (issue) Windows 10:

[image]

```css
.button__btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-align: center;
}

.button__btn:active,
.button__btn:focus {
  outline: 1px dotted black;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button class="button__btn">I'm a default button</button>
</div>
```

Here's also a codepen: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/EORBpE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use following code:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
   border: 0;
}
```

It will remove firefox inner outline for all buttons.

this suggestion was also mentioned here: [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Comment: Yes, I found the same link on the internet some hours ago. Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be also a bug of a specific firefox version: I'm on Windows 10 and my firefox is 63.0.3 (64-Bit). My collegue has the same issue on a Macbook with the same firefox version, while another collegue does not have this bug on a different version.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**CSS**

```
.button{
     -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
      -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer - Edge */
          user-select: none; /* Chrome and Opera */
}
```

> The user-select property specifies whether the text of an element can
>   be selected.

Comment: I tried it, but the issue is still there... I'm using Windows 10... A friend of mine tried it on Firefox Mac and he can not reproduce the issue, it looks the same as on chrome...