# Changing border color when button is clicked

Tags: html, css

If you click on the button, you will see a blue border, which is really annoying for me. Do you have any solutions on how to make it disappear/not appear at all?

```css
button{
    color: aqua;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button>about</button>
```

Comment: `button:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}`

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/#article-header-id-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a `border` but the `outline` of the button. You can remove it adding `outline: none` to it, but you should consider adding an alternative for those who use the keyboard to navigate.

```css
button{
    color: aqua;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<button>about</button>
```

Comment: If you care also for Firefox, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links

Comment: I think adding the prefix is no longer necessary: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline