# Difference between pseudo-classes -moz-focus-inner and -moz-focusring

Tags: css, pseudo-class

It seems to me that the pseudo-classes -moz-focus-inner and -moz-focusring have the same task.

Although I often see the property -moz-focus-inner in examples, it does not seem to have any effect on the formatting of form elements, unlike -moz-focusring (at least under Firefox 66 / Win).

Can someone explain to me what the difference between the two properties is and if and when I need -moz-focus-inner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-moz-focusring` is a Mozilla only, non-standard pseudo-class extension that should not be used in production because it's not on a standards track. Mozilla suggests that some developers have used it to differeniate between users focusing via mouse click versus focusing via keyboard tabbing. `focusring` hasn't been defined in any specification yet. It only matches if the element *already* has focus and the dev determines that a focus ring should be drawn around it.

`-moz-focus-inner` is an active layer (their implmentation of `focus-inner`) that adds a border to focused buttons, not in replacement of the default focus outline but in *addition* to it (in the form of a inner dotted black border). This appears to be typically unwanted behavior that can be eliminated by using `normalize.css` for example, or just writing your own custom rule:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
}
```

As to why Mozilla has implemented `-moz-focus-inner` in a way that annoys lots of developers? I guess that's down to its being a project with a long history of contributions and experiments. But the main difference, from a development perspective, is that you typically will need to "deal" with `-moz-focus-inner` in some way, probably by eliminating it via custom CSS rule (unless you *want* the additional FF version of this visual focus indicator), whereas `-moz-focusring` is representative of a non-standard psuedo-class being discussed by the Working Group that may become part of the specification at some future point (Selectors 4 or 5).

**Sources**

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-moz-focusring
2. https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/issues/393
3. [How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links/199319#199319)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer ! -moz-focus-inner is a is a pseudo element - is that correct ?

Comment: Hmm. That's a good question. Based on the definition of a "psuedo-class," it appears to me  at leat that `-moz-focus-inner` would fall under that category: i.e., the application of a "phantom class" in the event of a dynamic element state that is entered into and exited out of. Psuedo elements allow one to define logical elements that are not actually in the document tree. But maybe someone else will have a better clarification...?

Comment: If you believe mine is a sufficient answer to your question, please consider marking the question answered. Thanks, @Janek!