# Firefox bug? Got unwanted (and uncoded) strokes on img (working on others browsers)

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

I'm currently tuning a file input for displaying its content using a preview `<img>` tag.

```py
<div id="image_preview">
    <input> ..... 
    <img id="preview" src="" class="img-fluid" alt="">
</div>
```

Using some CSS, it renders correctly on Chrome but I got a black stroke on every side of the square on Firefox (and only on Firefox). I tried to set a "border: none;" or even a transparent background but none of these are working as expected. Any hints?

Thanks for any kind of help :)

[image: Correct file input on chrome]
[image: Problem on Firefox]

Comment: since the black lines are grey on the bottom, i think we are looking at `box-shadow` or some sort of `underline`, there is more css options for this then just `border`, i'd suggest checking for shadow or underline/line styling

Comment: Maybe check the css "outline"?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. I found that Firefox is adding these lines only on blank img src. I added a blank image base64 string and it's working fine now.

Thanks for your help :)

If needed : `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAPcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAP8ALAAAAAABAAEAAAgEAP8FBAA7`

Answer (score 0):

Firefox usually adds a dotted line, this can be removed and an SO user answered this question:

[How to remove Firefox's dotted outline on BUTTONS as well as links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links)

Basically writing in your CSS this `::-moz-focus-inner`

```css
.img-fluid::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
}
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Didn't know. Thanks :) But it's look like it's not related to my problem as your snippet isn't working. I'm still trying to find a solution. Anyway, thank you, I learnt something :)

Comment: @JeromeDesseaux you can see solutions in the SO post link that I mentioned. Maybe your 'dotted line' is for the input.

Comment: No because it renders fine as soon  as I remove (or display: none) the img :)