# How to get rid of blue outline when a button is being held down?

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with my website where when I hold down a button, the button is outlined with blue. I have tried this code but it did not work:

```
button {
   outline: none !important;
}
```

and

```
button:focus {
   outline: none !important;
}
```

Either way, I do not want to use that code because apparently it is bad for website accessibility.

Is there a way to get rid of the blue outline?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what did you try?

Comment: :focus {outline:none;}
::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074/how-to-remove-firefoxs-dotted-outline-on-buttons-as-well-as-links?rq=1

Comment: _"Either way, I do not want to use that code because apparently it is bad for website accessibility."_ Source?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
button:focus{
outline: none;}
```

I have done if my own, if you still got some error then send me HTML