# IE - Prevent focus (click, doubleclick) on a select box if it has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm using javascript to simulate a disabled select element. I can't actually disable it as the .net validators fail, but that's another story.

I have the following function:

```
function preventFocus(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.blur();
  }
}
```

That is called here:

```
$("#ProvinceID").toggleClass("disabled").bind('focus click dblclick', preventFocus);
```

Double-clicking the select box in IE still seems to allow the items to be displayed and selected. I tried the IE developer toolbar, and the e.type is showing up as focus and dblclick. Is this an IE bug, or do I need to catch some other event? I also tried focusin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is 4 years late but I just discovered there is in fact a way to get IE ≤ 8 to do what `e.preventDefault()` on `mousedown` does in other browsers (which prevents selection **and** prevents focus): set the `unselectable` attribute! http://jsbin.com/yagekiji/1

Note that unlike the workarounds always suggested, which always boil down to `setTimeout(function() { thingIDidntWantFocusStolenFrom.focus(); })`, this prevents focus from ever being stolen by the `mousedown` target in the first place!

What's funny about `unselectable` is that it isn't inherited, so it's often overlooked in favor of the `selectstart` event (which bubbles, and `e.preventDefault()` on which prevents selection but **doesn't** prevent focus), or set on every descendant element with a tree-traversal (like [the StackOverflow answer that first clued me in that this might be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17525223/362030), or Tim Down's [series](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448972/362030) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4358620/362030) [nearly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2326028/362030) [identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448965/362030) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209958/362030)), but you can actually just set it on `event.target` on `mousedown`.

(Also, jQuery ticket: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10345)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's just a typo, but you should use e.preventDefault(); looks like you were missing the parenthesis.

Comment: Typo, yes; answer, no. Thanks though.