# Prevent selection in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, selection

I have a div on a HTML page and whenever I press the mouse and move it, it will show that "can't drop" cursor like it selects something. Is there a way to disable selection? I tried CSS user-select with none without success.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The proprietary variations of `user-select` will work in most modern browsers:

```
*.unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

For IE < 10 and Opera, you will need to use the `unselectable` attribute of the element you wish to be unselectable. You can set this using an attribute in HTML:

```
<div id="foo" unselectable="on" class="unselectable">...</div>
```

Sadly this property isn't inherited, meaning you have to put an attribute in the start tag of every element inside the `<div>`. If this is a problem, you could instead use JavaScript to do this recursively for an element's descendants:

```
function makeUnselectable(node) {
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        node.setAttribute("unselectable", "on");
    }
    var child = node.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        makeUnselectable(child);
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}

makeUnselectable(document.getElementById("foo"));
```

Comment: it's not selected but still copied to the clipboard (according to the MDC spec at http://goo.gl/5P8uH)

Comment: @ithkuil: Interesting. Looks like `-moz-none` is the way to go. I'll amend my answer.

Comment: In Firefox 5, `-moz-none` seems not to be autocompleted by Firebug although `none` is: `-moz-user-select: none` (works)

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Both work to prevent selection, but there is notionally a difference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select. However, the following does not seem to back this up in Firefox 5: http://jsfiddle.net/vhwJ5/2/.

Comment: i'm pretty sure `user-select` only deals with text and no other kind of elements

Answer (score 12):

It's seem CSS user-select don't prevent image drag and drop... so..

HTML :

```
<img src="ico.png" width="20" height="20" alt="" unselectable="on" /> Blabla bla blabla
```

CSS :

```
* {
     user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
}

::selection { background: transparent;color:inherit; }
::-moz-selection { background: transparent;color:inherit; }
```

JS :

```
$(function(){
    $('*:[unselectable=on]').mousedown(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use "img" selector but be carefull with "event.preventDefault();" because no others events associated with "mousedown" will work on them in your page...

Answer (score 5):

I use `cancelBubble=true` and `stopPropagation()` in the mouse down and move handlers.

Comment: What snagged me was that you need it in _both_ the mouse down and move handlers, not just the move one!

Answer (score 4):

`event.preventDefault()` seems to do the trick (tested in IE7-9 and Chrome) :

```
jQuery('#slider').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    var handler, doc = jQuery(document);
    e.preventDefault();
    doc.on('mousemove', handler = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // refresh your screen here
    });
    doc.one('mouseup', function (e) {
        doc.off('mousemove', handler);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this, searched for awhile on the proper way to block a select I list I was blocking on click, since disabled values don't post..... haha

Answer (score 1):

Have you got some sort of transparent image that your selecting? Usually the "cant drop" icon appears when you drag an image. Otherwise it normally selects text when you drag. If so you might have to put the image behind everything using z-index.