# Constrain user selection to node without making it editable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, selection

I have the following page:

```
<div class="a">
  ...
</div>
<div class="b">
  ...
</div>
```

My users interact with this page by selecting various pieces of text within `.a` and `.b`. The browser's native selection behaviour almost works, but I need to prevent my users from making selections, which span the boundary between `.a` and `.b`.

Is there a way to constrain the user's selection to a `<div>`?

Unfortunately, this content is *not* user editable - which is unfortunate, because setting `contenteditable="true"` on each `<div>` achieves the constraint I'm looking for.

Comment: Why not use `textarea`s instead?

Comment: @Diodeus hmm, and disable them? Let me try.

Comment: You can also use an Iframe, and style it to look unobtrusive.

Comment: @Diodeus a disabled textarea is not selectable (at least in FF). iframe might limit what I can do with the javascript.

Comment: I never suggested disabling it.

Comment: @Diodeus content isn't editable. Are you seeing something I'm not there? How do you deal with that in a textarea?

Comment: I'd suggest the iframe as the most fool-proof method.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2326028/592253

Comment: The `user-select` property has the `element` option.  Unfortunately and somewhat paradoxically, this option is supported only in IE.  Otherwise, you would have had a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about starting with this:

HTML:

```
<div class = "a">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id semper purus. Duis laoreet tellus in ante luctus semper. Praesent interdum urna quis luctus commodo.
</div>
<div class = "b">
    Curabitur vehicula eget leo a tristique. Donec eget aliquam erat. Mauris id porttitor lacus. 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 10px;
}

.noSelection {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

div + div {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("div").hover(function() {
        $(this).siblings("div").toggleClass("noSelection");    
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J2fJz/.